# Small Webpage to check open ports on IP

Tags: javascript, ios, web, html

I know that there are already many services out there for this, but I want to make my own for a small project to gain more knowledge.

I have made a Java application that can check if a port is open on an IP address, wether it's some like 12.345.67.890 or www.site.org or even 192.168.0.1

I want to implement the same thing into a webpage. I can't use any sort of Java Applets as I want to use it on mobile devices as well (iPhone doesn't allow Java, except JS). JavaScript is fine. I have tried examining code on pages that already do this, but I can't find anything useful. I only know HTML, but am willing to learn JavaScript. I have no knowledge of PHP or asp but am willing to learn.

If anyone can supply a tutorial that can be customized or code I can implement I would be happy to add you in a "credits" section.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: My Java program is like a very minimal version of nMap (minimal meaning 2 text boxes and a button)

Comment: Do you have the java project hosted anywhere? It's sometimes easier to port than to implement from scratch. It'd also be helpful to see what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @Brandon Here is the Dropbox link: bit.ly/28TuSNb

Comment: "iPhone doesn't allow Java, except JS" JavaScript and Java are note related. Do not conflate the two. Normal Java code does not work in JavaScript, and vice versa. The two are related in the same way that nuclear reactors and ears are related -- the way one is spelled happens to contain the way the other is spelled.